# Items are not coming one by one

Tags: beamer, itemize

I learnt that the following code work for displaying items one by one

```
\begin{frame}{one by one}
\begin{itemize}
    \item<1-> a;

    \item<2-> b;

    \item<3-> c;
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

But all are coming in a single frame once. One by one are not coming. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Simply adding `\documentclass{beamer} \begi{document}` and `\end{document}` in order to make your code compilable results in three slides, with the first one including the first item, the second one including the first and secons item and the last slide containing all three items. If you get a different output, the reason is most likely hidden in a part of the code you did not include.

Comment: Yeah, in Beamer only, but the presentation is too big to post.

Comment: Do not include the whole presentation but reduce your document to a so called [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). To do so, make a copy of your document, comment out some frames, reocmpile and see if the problem persists. If so, comment out more code and repeat. With this method you should be able to produce a MWE that is small enough to be posted here and that allows others to reproduce the issue you describe.